# listview, checkbox, c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have ListView which shows images from an ImageList. Now wanted to get index of all checked images in ListView.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(); // in list index of all checked images on clicking button should be saved.

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView.CheckedListViewItemCollection checkedItems = lstview1.CheckedItems;

    foreach (ListViewItem item in checkedItems)
    {
      list.add[// How can i get index of checked item ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListView already has the CheckedIndices property.  You probably ought to use it directly, but you can get a List<> out of it with a Linq one-liner:

```
        var list = listView1.CheckedIndices.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but you can get the index of a ListViewItem with `item.Index`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView.CheckedListViewItemCollection checkedItems = lstview1.CheckedItems;

foreach (ListViewItem item in checkedItems)
{
      // This will fill the list with ListViewItems that are checked
      list.add(listview1.Items[item.Index]);
}
```

Comment: I tried already but it comes  best overloaded match method for list<int> has invalid parameters. when

Comment: I tried already but it comes  best overloaded match method for list<int> has invalid parameters. when i want to show in messagebox i understand reason but donot know how to fix it.                 MessageBox.Show(lstview1.Items[item.Index].ToString()); //shows  listviewitem={}